# Check array value from HTML in ruby script

Tags: html, ruby

I am writing a ruby script code to extract data from from the following html code.

```
<script>
    parameter = [{
        'Site_Language': 'en',
        'Category1': 'asdas',
        'Product': 'asdasd',
        'Product2': 'asdasd',

    }];
</script>
```

How can I access the array element Category1? Should I have to use a simple text() search and access the array? Can somebody help please?

Comment: Do you parse the html?

Comment: I am not sure. I want to access the array data inside the <script>.

Comment: Question is not clear. Are you parsing HTML data in Ruby using a parser like nokogiri? or you want to access `parameter` in HTML code? or you want to parse string from `<script>...</script>` in Ruby and get the JSON object inside it?

Answer (score -1):

```
   <script>
        parameter = [{
            'Site_Language': 'en',
            'Category1': 'asdas',
            'Product': 'asdasd',
            'Product2': 'asdasd',

        }];

     parameter[0]['Category1'] //asdas

    </script>
```

You can loop through the parameter arrays

Comment: Outside of tag `<script>`?